# Ngprime directive menu issue

Tags: angular

Good morning,
i'm trying to set open a p-menu (https://primeng.org/menu) of ngprimes, sakai theme on a project. Following the documentation I set the open on click using the directive as an element:

```
<p-toast></p-toast>
<p-menu #menu [model]="items" [popup]="true"></p-menu>
<button pButton type="button" (click)="menu.toggle($event)" icon="pi pi-bars" label="Show"></button>
```

but I get a compile-time error: Property 'toggle' does not exist on type 'HTMLDivElement'. Did you mean 'ontoggle'?

I think the import of a module is missing but I can't figure out which one, could you help me?
https://codesandbox.io/s/imb2le?file=/src/app/app.module.ts